Move 3 switches from entry wall to side of pantry
re doing kitchen need to move 3 switches from wall to pantry cabinet side distance 12 inch. My thoughts are to install metal cover plate drill holes for connectors and run BX to new box? Please share your thoughts. Thanks Bill

Are the switches beside a doorway or someplace else?  Do not know the code, but think it says something about a room light switch needing to be close to a doorway(need to find it in the dark).

"metal cover plate" implies to me that you're thinking of then covering this with drywall. That is 100% a code violation. If there is a wiring connection inside the box, it must remain accessible with nothing more than a screwdriver.
